# Enum bit operations with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin

I'm trying to port program from .net to Mono on Mac OS X, but I can't compile it while I'm getting compilation error. What Should I do to compile it ? Why on windows it works fine?

I'm new to C#, especially on mac os.

```
namespace my-project
{
    using System;

    [Flags]
    public enum MyEnum : uint
    {
        F_FLAG_1 = 0x00004,
        F_FLAG_2 = 0x00008
    }
 }
```

Code line with error:

```
if ((this.MyEnumField & num) != 0)
```

Compilation Error message:

```
Error CS0019: Operator `&' cannot be applied to operands of type `MyEnum' and `uint' (CS0019) (my-project)
```

I'm using Xamarin studio.

Comment: Ok. seems I've found a solution - it requires explicit cast num to MyEnum... May be there is some compiler settings to avoid such casts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read it as anything else than that Mono is in the right, the C# spec has this to say;

> **Enum values and operations**
>
> Each enum type defines a distinct type; *an explicit enumeration conversion (§6.2.2) is required to convert between an enum type and an integral type*, or between two enum types

...and...

> **Enumeration logical operators**
>
> Every enumeration type E implicitly provides the following predefined logical operators:
>
> - E operator &(E x, E y);
> - E operator |(E x, E y);
> - E operator ^(E x, E y);

That is, the logical operators are only defined enum*enum, and to use an integral type in a logical expression with an enum, it *should* require an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

If it compiles with .NET and not in Mono, it's a mono compiler bug, please report it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/